# Querying on multiple joined rows

Tags: postgresql, redshift, relational-division

I have a table called `visits` that is structured like so:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | name         | visitor_id  |
|----+--------------+-------------+
| 1  | event1       | 1           |
| 2  | event2       | 2           |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

I have a table called `params` that is structured like so:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| id | a_key        | a_value       | visit_id      |
|----+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | key1         | value1        | 1             |
| 2  | key2         | value2        | 1             |
| 3  | key3         | value3        | 1             |
| 4  | key1         | value1        | 2             |
| 5  | key2         | value2        | 2             |
+----+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

This query looks for visits with params that are 'key1' and 'value1'.

```
select *
from visits
right join params as p on p.visit_id = visits.id
where a_key = 'key1' and a_value = 'value1'
```

I need to write a query that will give me all the visits that have params 'key1', 'value1' and **also** 'key3', 'value3'. In this case it would only return visit 1.

What is the most performant way to achieve this?

I thought about joining the params on again, but that doesn't seem like the best solution.

Here it is in a fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06773/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division).
We have assembled an arsenal of query techniques in this related answer on SO:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774879/939860)

For your case this query will be among the fastest possible solutions:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   params p1
JOIN   params p3 USING (visit_id)
JOIN   visits v  ON v.id = p3.visit_id
WHERE  p1.a_key = 'key1' AND p1.a_value = 'value1'
AND    p3.a_key = 'key3' AND p3.a_value = 'value3';
```

If you just need the `visit_id` you don't even need to join to table `visits`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a1ffac8944c6b7fd96f9f538edd00e76)*
Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cbdab/1).